# Disable "save as" option

Tags: browser

How can i disable "save as" option from any browser File option menu?
I need to protect my content. I have disable right click , ctrl-a, ctrl-c and print screen.
Still have the save as option.

Is it possible?

Comment: I regret to inform that you don't even need a browser to download stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible. No browser supports it, but even without a browser, you can download files over HTTP.

Try this command line (works well with Unix and Windows):

```
telnet www.google.com 80
GET /
```

See? No browser needed.

You can of course make it difficult for end users to download the contents of the pages by hiding it with an HTML Obfuscator, like so: http://htmlobfuscator.com.

Comment: I do have .aspx pages(.net website) and not .html pages , can this HTML Obfuscator be helpful in this case?

Comment: @Mahag, I don't know, I haven't used this tool myself.